# Can't make Vue Axios request from one pod to another pod's service, but I can curl from another pod to the service

Tags: kubernetes, vuejs2, axios, kubernetes-ingress

I have a backend pod with a SpringBoot application, and a frontend pod with a Vue application running. I've been taking things step by step to learn more about Kubernetes. The goal right now, is to make a GET request from the Vue app to my SpringBoot App. This works fine if I run both apps in their respective environment locally (npm build run, and just running the SpringBoot app).

I've then moved them into pod containers backed by services in Kubernetes. Both work on their own, but I can't get my Vue application to make the GET request with Axios. (And I have allowed all CORS origin access, so that **shouldn't** be the problem atleast)

I've been looking into other questions, and also reading a bunch of documentation. I am not sure if running Kubernetes locally can do this, or if I need to setup a domain name? I've seen a bunch of ingress examples where they make use of hostnames, and I've also looked into environment variables.

1. I don't have a domain, I'm running my kubernetes cluster on Docker
2. I have environment variables inside my Vue container, one that I've made myself and some that was made by Kubernetes itself that actually points to the local IP of my backend/SpringBoot's pod's IP. (Which basically is RESTSERVICE_PORT_8080_ADDR, RESTSERVICE_SERVICE_PORT_8080_8080)
3. It's my understanding that I should be able to keep the backend pod closed from the outside. By referencing the service, I should be able to make the GET request. **I can deploy a pod that sends a CURL to the backend's servicename, which works.** But using the very same adress in my Vue app does not work. Why is that? I've read it's something about the browser + my Vue app needing access but how do I set that up correctly?

**So basically I've looked into using environment variables, which I can't figure out how to make use of inside the Vue app in the container. And I've also tried just reaching out to the service's adress which works with a CURL, but not from the Vue AXIOS request.**

- I can also configure Ingress, but this opens my backend service/pod up to the public as well, which I understand is something I should be able to refrain from doing. **Like I mentionned, ideally I should be able to reach the service of the backend pod without opening it up to the public right?**

Here is the pod + service configuration for my backend code. It's a YAML file that was autoconfigured via some Spring guide if I remember correctly and I've just reused it since. It has some boilerplate so sorry about that:

**SpringBoot pod + service configuration YAML:**

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: restservice
      name: restservice
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: restservice
      strategy: {}
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            app: restservice
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: restservice
            image: restservice
            imagePullPolicy: Never
    status: {}
    --- 
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: restservice
      name: restservice
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: 8080-8080
        port: 8080
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8080
      selector:
        app: restservice
      type: ClusterIP
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: restservice
      name: restservice
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: 8080-8080
        port: 8080
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8080
      selector:
        app: restservice
      type: ClusterIP
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
```

And here is the YAML configuration for my frontend application, which is basically the same configuration except here I am now using a LoadBalancer as the type of the service.

**Vue pod + service configuration YAML:**

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1 kind: Deployment metadata:   creationTimestamp: null   labels:
        app: vuejs   name: vuejs spec:   replicas: 1   selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: vuejs   strategy: {}   template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            app: vuejs
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: vuejs
            image: vuejs
            env:
            - name: RESTSERVICE_API_URL
              value: "restservice:8080"
            imagePullPolicy: Never status: {}
    ---  apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata:   creationTimestamp: null   labels:
        app: vuejs   name: vuejs spec:   ports:
      - name: 8082-8082
        port: 8082
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8082   selector:
        app: vuejs   type: LoadBalancer status:   loadBalancer: {} apiVersion: v1 kind: Service metadata:   creationTimestamp: null   labels:
        app: vuejs   name: vuejs spec:   ports:
      - name: 8082-8082
        port: 8082
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8082   selector:
        app: vuejs   type: LoadBalancer status:   loadBalancer: {}
```

My call via Axios in Vue is just a regular GET request. I can provide it if needed but like I said, it worked when running the applications locally, it's just not working within the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I have answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64171702/9422621

Comment: I've dug around and come to the conclusion that this is the answer as well in this scenario. I am actually adding another service in the mix, which contains a database. Here I'm again sort of thinking, is ingress the only answer?

Comment: One thing that doesn't make sense to me however is this:
I just now made use of Environment Variables to reach a Pod running a Postgres image from my SpringBoot Application. So by using the TCP address Environment variable, I can reach the Postgres pod without an ingress.

Why is this not doable here? Could I not just inject the TCP address via Environment Variables to my Vue application?

Comment: I think you’re confusing what the role of ingress is. Ingress is is designed to to serve HTTP traffic. Databases in general operate over TCP. In your case, a Service object will do the job, and route traffic to your database. So set environment var to service name (if in diff namespace, include the namespace as well)

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "doesn't work" ? As far as I understand when you run `curl restservice:8080` everything works correctly, right ? So what exactly happens when you make a `GET` request from your `Pod` to the very same `Service` ? Do you get any error message ? Is there anything in your app logs ? And how you exactly make this request ? Did you specify only service name and port or are there any other steps involved ? You don't need any ingress in this scenario. Simple `ClusterIP` `Service` should be more than enough.